# How many Joneses are there in the Whoniverse?

Tags: doctor-who, names

As far as last names go, this one gets reused about as much as the average British actor, so... how many Joneses (or separate Jones families) have been in Doctor Who or any spinoffs?

Off the top of my head, I can think of Martha, Ianto, Harriet, and Jo (née Grant). How many others have there been?

Comment: Why would you care? Why would *anyone* care about something like this?

Comment: @Gallifreian Curiosity?

Comment: Jones is the second most common surname in the UK, only Smith is more common., which might explain why it is used so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Doctor Who wiki article for "Jones"](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jones) lists **26** individuals known to have the surname 'Jones', some explictly named, some merely supposed (based on their parentage or surnames of offspring).

> **Regular characters and companions**
>
> - [Ianto Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Ianto_Jones)
> - [Jo Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jo_Jones)
> - [Martha Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Martha_Jones) (Martha-Smith Jones)
> - [Samantha Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Samantha_Jones)
> - [John Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/John_Jones)
>
> **Others**
>
> - Billy Jones
> - Clifford Jones
> - Eugene Jones
> - Harriet Jones
> - Gordon Jones
> - Jones (The Dæmons)
> - Jones (The Enemy of the World)
> - Captain Jones
> - Mr Jones
> - Mrs Jones
>
> **FAMILIES**
>
> *Martha Jones' family*:     Clive Jones
>    - Francine Jones
>    - Tish Jones
>    - Leo Jones
>    - Keisha Jones
>
> *Eugene Jones' family*:     Bronwen Jones
>    - Shaun Jones
>    - Terry Jones
>
> *Eliza Jones' family*:     Eliza Jones
>    - Sammy Jones
>    - Eliza Jones' mother